# Database cannot be opened because it is offline. But it is excluded allready in select..

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get this error:
Msg 942, Level 14, State 4, Line 2
Database 'TESTNA' cannot be opened because it is offline.

```
select name 
from sys.databases 
where state = 0  -- exclude offline databases
    and name <> db_name() -- exclude current dataase
    and OBJECT_ID (name+'.dbo.some_table','U') is not null  -- returns all   databases with some_table
```

I don't get it. Why this error? Database TESTNA is excluded with "state=0" condition.

Comment: How about adding a `USE master` at the beginning of your query?

Comment: Because your where predicate that is checking the OBJECT_ID has to query sys.objects for the given database and it is offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a case expression here to get around the problem of your where predicate. Something like this should do it.

```
select name, state 
from sys.databases 
where state = 0  -- exclude offline databases
    and name <> db_name() -- exclude current dataase
    and case when state = 0 then 
            case when OBJECT_ID (name+'.dbo.some_table','U') is not null then 1 end
        end = 1
```

Comment: Yes that solves the problem. Actually I don'd need the first condition "state=0". Tnx.